# Pytest assert message with http or https

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest

I'm using pytest to assert a message that contains an URL that was just http. But now, I'm also have https for the same message.
Does anyone have a clue to how can I handle the same message even if I receive http or https?
I've been looking after the regex, but couldn't find a way to deal with it. For now, my code is like:

```
assert (
    msg
    == "Client Error for url: http://..."
)
```

I'm trying to find a way to that message can assert this text even when get http or https.
Is that possible to do without create one assert for http and another for https?

Thank you all!

Comment: So what regex did you try that didn't work?

Comment: I didn't try actually because I couldn't find one that would be suitable for this.

Comment: A simple `"Client Error for url: https?://..."` should be sufficient.

Comment: Awesome! I will try it! Should it handle the message with http and https?

Comment: Well, yes, it's a simple regex. You should check the regex of course, e.g. something like `regex = re.compile("Client error..."); assert regex.match(msg)`.

Comment: So, this "?" will only work if I use regex? Should it work using a simple assert?

Comment: No, an assert just checks the expression you give it. A standard comparison operator will not magically change to a regex operator.